# What is more secure than http.server package in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http

I'm building an Http file server using python so I'm using http.server python built-in package like the following

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

from io import BytesIO


class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(b'Hello, world!')

    def do_POST(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        body = self.rfile.read(content_length)
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        response = BytesIO()
        response.write(b'This is POST request. ')
        response.write(b'Received: ')
        response.write(body)
        self.wfile.write(response.getvalue())


httpd = HTTPServer(('255.255.255.255', 8000), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

so I've read that this package is not recommended for production. It only implements basic security checks. 
are there any alternatives or a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Python library is not intended to provide a high performance and highly secure http server. It just allows to build both simply and quickly an *acceptable* http server meeting your functional requirements. If you want to use it in production, just hide it behind an Apache or nginx reverse proxy. That way, only the secure proxy will be exposed to internet.

That is what is commonly done for professional grade Tomcat application servers.

Comment: I don't want to use my app online if it happens to know HFS software I want to build something simpler